# How to draw this chart in html and CSS?

Tags: css, html, flowchart

Please how to do this chart in HTML and CSS ??

Where the circles are buttons ..
[image]

Comment: This is not a code generating service, try yourself and ask questions about the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Use an image map. [Here is an image map generator](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/). Hardly any coding skills needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:
**Your basic circle:**

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;  /*Make it a circle (border-radius = 1/2*width & height)*/
  background-color: hotPink;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="circle">Motion Detection</button>
<!-- Using a button to generate the circle -->
```

Then use `position: absolute;` with the `left` and `right` properties to position the circles.

Have a `Live positioned in the middle of your page with:

```
<style>
 #text {
    font-family: MyFont, sans-serif;
    color: white;
 }
<style>
```

---

For the lines I would use divs, and give them a height of 2px and a width of what ever (350px for example.) For the positioning, again use the position property (learn how to use it here: w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) –  joe_young just now   edit

---

Use the above to help you create what you want, but as has already been said,

> This is not a code generating service, try yourself and ask questions about the code you're having trouble with.

In other words, have a go, come back to us when you have tried and have a specific problem.
Good luck

Comment: but how to add connection to each circle as the image and keep them located correctly ?

Comment: For the lines I would use `divs`, and give them a height of `2px` and a width of what ever (`350px` for example.) For the positioning, again use the `position` property (learn how to use it here: **http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp**)